# c++11 constexpr function cannot receive "const" return value?

Tags: c++11, compilation, char, constants, constexpr

New to c++11 `constexpr`, I'm using latest clang++-14 version on windows and try to see how `const` and `constexpr` could work together.

I've got a global variable of char* and wish to return it, in a `constexpr` function, as below:

```
char* pHello = "hello";
constexpr char* hello() {
    return pHello; // compilation error
}
```

It doesn't compile, clang says:

```
Constexpr function never produces a constant expressionclang(-Winvalid-constexpr)
xxxcpp(20, 12): Read of non-constexpr variable 'pHello' is not allowed in a constant expression
xxx.cpp(18, 7): Declared here
```

Then in the first line, I added a `const`:

```
const char* pHello = "hello"; // add const here
constexpr char* hello() {
    return pHello; // still compilation error
}
```

This time, the clang error became:

```
Cannot initialize return object of type 'char *' with an lvalue of type 'const char *'clang(init_conversion_failed)
```

Reading this error message, I tried to modify the `hello()` signature as:

```
constexpr const char* hello() {
```

Now the error became same as original:

```
Constexpr function never produces a constant expressionclang(-Winvalid-constexpr)
xxx.cpp(20, 12): Read of non-constexpr variable 'pHello' is not allowed in a constant expression
xxx.cpp(18, 13): Declared here
```

I make this test just to see how `constexpr` and `const` would work together, but even when I change the global variable as also `constexpr` like this:

```
constexpr char* pHello = "hello";
constexpr char* hello() {
    return pHello;
}
```

Still doesn't compile:

```
error: cannot initialize return object of type 'char *' with an lvalue of type 'const char *'
    return pHello;
```

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `pHello` is `const char*` (a pointer to `const char`), and add `constexpr` to make it a [constant expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression).

The return type of function `hello` should be consistent with `pHello`, you can't lose constness here. `constexpr` here is only used to mark this function a constexpr function.

```cpp
constexpr const char* pHello = "hello";
constexpr const char* hello() {
    return pHello;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9rjdGehPG)